# Tactics for high score on Plague Inc

Tags: plague-inc

I find the iOS game "Plague Inc" pretty easy since the same tactic seems to work on every level.

*I simply evolve air and water transmission along with cold and drug resistance until every single human being is infected.
After that I just evolve coughing, "immunity something" and the next one giving me total organ collapse. The bodies hit the floor after that and the DNA points given during the downfall of society is invested in mitigating the effects of the cure.
This tactic never fails me (I play normal difficulty) but it never seems to give me a better than average score (3 / 5 biohazard symbols).*

**My question:**

What is the score based upon? Time to complete the level? % cure developed? If I completed the level with minimum evolution? Something else? Everything above?

If you don't know the above; Do you get higher scores? How?

Comment: Since this looks a lot like Pandemic, I will simply say that I too am curious to learn about the best method to eradicate Madagascar.

Comment: My method for Madagascar... Well Generally the last country left for me is Greenland or the Caribbean, and they have only ports so I'll upgrade water infectivity more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PAX-12
DNA Sequence: Complex

Difficulty: Normal

Disease Type: Parasite

Time: 1050 days

Cure Progress: 20% complete

Score Total: 36630

4/5 bio's

My tactic was basically the same. I also believe you get more bio's on brutal. Except I go for coma as well to make it harder to cure. Along with paralysis and paranoia, coming from the insomnia line mainly.

But to answer your question, I believe it is mainly calculated by cure progress. Just did it again in 635 days, but 52% cure progress (less resistance upgrade more lethality) and got 12k score with 3 bio's.

A test on brutal, also testing DNA points left over:

Complex

Brutal

Bacteria

2018 days

98% complete

6230pts

3bio's

To me this says that cure progress is still most important, as I had nearly 60 DNA points left over (it was quite hard to do that on brutal btw, barely did it (first try though ;)

Comment: Have not tested this but who am I to question your science?

Comment: Testing it is hard... It takes a while. Those are the honest results of three specific tests. I did some more overnight with basically the same results. Only time I get 4 bio's (never earned 5 yet) is with low cure percentage. Which makes parasite fantastic for earning bio's.