# How does the scoring in Plague inc work?

Tags: plague-inc

I am doing better and better but can’t seem to really knock it out of the park. How much do you have to wipe stuff out to get all five badges here?

[image: 4 star run on 'Brutal' difficulty]

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How to get 5 biohazards?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156833/how-to-get-5-biohazards) | [Tactics for high score on Plague Inc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73478/4797)

Answer (score -2):

Scoring for Plague inc seems to be based on how quickly you completed a successful round. It also depends on how many evolutions/upgrades you used in your round. The best way to get a high score seems to win quickly with as few evolutions/upgrades as you possibly can.